# SQL DISTINCT id when SUM weight in sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have two types of sub query's in the statement.
First of all some sample data.

**Table**

```
CAT   ID    Weight   GROUP
1      1     200     A  
1      2     300     B  
1      3     250     B 
1      1     200     A  
1      4     200     A
```

One sub query is a count of distinct IDs which works as expected.

```
( SELECT COUNT (distinct t1.ID) 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.group = 'A'
GROUP BY t1.cat)
AS [count],
```

The other sub query is a sum of the weight

```
( SELECT SUM(t1.weight) 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.group = 'A'
GROUP BY t1.cat)
AS [weight],
```

This doesn't give me what i need as it will total 600 when I want it to total 400 as i want only to use unique ID's as the first query does.

However by adding distinct...

```
( SELECT SUM(DISTINCT t1.weight) 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.group = 'A'
GROUP BY t1.cat)
AS [weight],
```

This only returns 200 as it is using distinct weight, what i want is it to use distinct ID in this, but how can i do this while still only selecting the weight?

Something like (logically speaking as this doesn't work)

```
( SELECT SUM(t1.weight) 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.group = 'A'
AND t1.ID IS DISTINCT
GROUP BY t1.cat)
AS [weight],
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key on `t1`?

Comment: Does it happen for 2 identical ids to have different weight?

Comment: But, how to chose t1.weight if there are two different values for a t1.cat?

Comment: Add another row to your sample data, "1      1     400     A".

Comment: This is not beautiful but; does it work? (SELECT SUM(subTable.weight) 
FROM (SELECT t1.ID As ID, MAX(t1.weight) As weight, t1.GROUP As GROUP
   FROM table t1
   GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.GROUP
) subTable
WHERE subTable.group = 'A'
GROUP BY subTable.cat)
AS [weight],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT cat,SUM(weight) AS [weight] FROM 
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as rn
 FROM table ) as tbl
WHERE [group] = 'A' AND rn=1
GROUP BY cat
```

Comment: @Matt Maybe it would be helpful if you post your main query somewhere online so we can take a look at it.The one above on its own will work.

Comment: Got it working with your code :) it was the as tb1 that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, as  I've looked at your sample data and what I believe is your desired output, but can you not just do a simple `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData
    ([CAT] int, [ID] int, [Weight] int, [GROUP] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO SampleData
    ([CAT], [ID], [Weight], [GROUP])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 200, 'A'),
    (1, 2, 300, 'B'),
    (1, 3, 250, 'B'),
    (1, 1, 200, 'A'),
    (1, 4, 200, 'A')
;

SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS [Counter], SUM(Weight) AS SumWeight
FROM SampleData
WHERE [GROUP] = 'A'
GROUP BY ID
```

To produce:

```
ID  Counter SumWeight
1   2       400
4   1       200
```

Comment: @Matt You get that error from running the above sql on it's own? I'm guessing not.

Comment: @Matt that's because your subquery is doing an `IN(...)` or something similar, so you can't just place my query, which returns 3 column in place of your subquery that expects a single column. This is just demonstrating the logic of how you can get the desired output, which would require a refactor of the main query in some way.